# FormData object add entire form without creating new object

Tags: jquery, form-data

I have a submit code as follows:

```
$(document).on("submit","form",function(event){
  event.preventDefault()
  formData=new FormData(this)
})
```

But sometimes I have the following done before the submit

```
formData=new FormData()    
formData.append("test",1)
```

As a result, calling a new FormData object deletes the appended data. How can I append the entire form without creating a new object? Something like this:

```
$(document).on("submit","form",function(event){
  event.preventDefault()
  FormData.append(this) // not new just appended entire form
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your `formData` variable is declared outside of your `.on("submit", "form", ...)` function.

You could use jquery's [`serializeArray()`](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) on your form. The `serializeArray()` function will return an array containing an object with a `name` and `value` property for each piece of data in your form. You can then loop through that array and use the `.append()` function on your `formData` instance to add all of the input from your form to the `formData`.

Note that you will need a `name` attribute on each element in your form for this to work properly. See the working example below, which will log each form item to the browser console before adding it to the `formData` instance.

```js
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("test", 1);

$(document).on("submit", "form", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var formDataArray = $(this).serializeArray();
  for(var i = 0; i < formDataArray.length; i++){
    var formDataItem = formDataArray[i];
    console.log(formDataItem);
    formData.append(formDataItem.name, formDataItem.value);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <label for="name">Name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name"/>
  <label for="age">Age:</label>
  <input type="number" id="age" name="age"/>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```